# How to generate families of sets without replacement symmetry?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to generate a family of sets with as few symmetries as possible. If convenient, let the size of each elements of the family be a fixed $s$ and the number of elements in the family be a fixed $n$. For my purposes, the set $\{\{a,b\},\{a,c\}\}$ in universe $U=\{a,b,c,d\}$ is equivalent to $\{\{b,a\},\{b,c\}\}$ (with $a$ and $b$ swapped) and also $\{\{d,b\},\{d,c\}\}$ (with $a$ and $d$ swapped). If you swap the names of any two variables, it doesn't change the underlying structure.

What are the formal names of this kind of equivalency? Given a universe set and size of the family how does one generate all possible families with no elements being equivalent under these conditions? I apologize if this is a well known problem. Searching hasn't really helped, I suspect because I'm using the wrong language to describe it.

Comment: If you are only considering only pairs of elements in $U$, then this is equivalent to finding graph isomorphisms. (Let $\{a,b,c,d\}$ be the vertices of the graph and any pair represent an edge in the graph.) I suspect that you need something more general, though, because it sounds like it is not just pairs you are considering.

Comment: I used pairs for the example. Yes I need it more general. I'll clarify the original post. Also thanks for the formatting.

Comment: Do [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) fit? Perhaps only those with [distinct parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts), so that only $4 = 4$ and $4 = 3 + 1$ would work here.

Comment: I just found out about [hypergraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph), and so your problem is equivalent to finding all isomorphically distinct hypergraphs of a given degree. From a set theory perspective, a keyword associated with this idea is a [family of sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets). Googling around, though, I couldn't find anything about counting/generating the family of sets where no two sets are *"isomorphic*".

Comment: @pjs36 How would the integer partitions map to families? Mapping integers to elements and sums to sets doesn't work.

Comment: You should edit this question to make it *exactly* clear what you are asking. Right now there are three parameters, $s$ and $n$ and $|U|$, and it is not clear which one(s) of these you really want to keep constant. Please outline a more concrete example.